# Getting error in HScrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.clarusapps.SwamiVivekananda.HScrollview.onTouchEvent(HScrollview.java:147)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5568)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2064)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2070)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1746)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2070)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1746)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2070)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1746)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2070)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1746)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2070)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1746)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1961)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1398)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2428)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1909)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5748)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3141)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:935)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2709)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4974)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show code, and which line it crashes.

Comment: `HScrollview.java line no 147` something is null in line no 147

Comment: I have placed this line at 147 --> final int availableToScroll = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1).getRight() - scrollX - getWidth();

Comment: I am not getting any crash or force close in my device at last view also, i am using Sony Xperia P with 4.0.3

Comment: I guess you need to remove this line to solve you problem^^

Answer (score 0):

Try following, it worked for me last time:

your_horizontal_scroll_view_object

```
final int availableToScroll = your_hsv_object.getChildAt(
    your_hsv_object.getChildCount() - 1).getRight() - scrollX - getWidth();
```

Comment: I think, it is because of getChildAt(int xyz) and getChildCount() comes from many class object.